# Python Opengl Freezing on mouse click

Tags: python, opengl, mouse

I am trying to implement a camera that moves when you click and drag. It uses glutMouseFunc to register mouse clicks which is just:

```
def on_click(self, button, state, x, y):
        if button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if state == GLUT_DOWN:
                self.dragging = True
                self.drag_x_origin = x
                self.drag_y_origin = y
            else:
                self.dragging = False
```

And in glutPassiveMotionFunc it has:

```
 def mouse_movement(self, x, y):
        print "----------------------"
        if self.dragging:
            print "+++++++++++"
```

which should at this point print "++++++++++++" but for some reason. It locks up. When I run the program I get an endless series of "----------------------", until I click, then it just stops. I have print in the display function, that still works, but for some reason this function locks up. Can anyone see why?

Mostly complete code:

```
class Camera():
    def __init__(self):
        self.camera_angle_horizontal = 1.0
        self.camera_angle_vertical = 1.0
        self.drag_x_origin = 0.0
        self.drag_y_origin = 0.0
        self.dragging = False

        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100)
        glutCreateWindow('cube')
        self.init()
        glutMouseFunc(self.on_click)
        glutPassiveMotionFunc(self.mouse_movement)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.display)
        glutReshapeFunc(self.reshape)
        glutKeyboardFunc(self.keyboard)
        glutMainLoop()

    def init(self):
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)

    def display(self):
        print self.dragging, self.camera_angle_vertical, self.camera_angle_horizontal
        ...
        glutPostRedisplay()

    def reshape(self, w, h):
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(40.0, w / h, 1.0, 20.0)
        #glFrustum (-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 20.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

    def on_click(self, button, state, x, y):
        if button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if state == GLUT_DOWN:
                self.dragging = True
            else:
                self.dragging = False

    def mouse_movement(self, x, y):
        print "----------------------"
        if self.dragging:
            print "+++++++++++"

c = Camera()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `glutPassiveMotionFunc(self.mouse_movement)` when I should have been using just  `gluteMotionFunc(self.mouse_movement)`

Comment: There is typo: `glutMotionFunc` instead of `gluteMotionFunc`